# Circular references in Objective-C and clang

Tags: objective-c, circular-reference

Why doesn't the static analyser detect circular references with blocks? I remember it used to do it when I had retains on my delegates instead of assign, pre-blocks introduction. I remember the nice little lines it used to draw on my code (i think...)

If I do this, without using weakSelf, I know I'm going to get a circular reference.

```
// Note 1: myObject is 'retained' by self. 
// Note 2: myObject retains the block for the future

[self.myObject registerBlockOfCodeForFutureExectution:^{
    [self doSomething];
}];
```

[Sample Project Exploiting Issue](https://github.com/devedup/CircularReferenceExample)

Now if I know this, and I'm a stupid human, then why doesn't my intelligent computer know this is bad and warn me that I'm being stupid?

There must be a logical reason why it can't detect it, and I want to know what that reason is.

This question is regarding clang and static analysis, please don't suggest how I fix circular references - I know how to do this.

Comment: It may not create a retain cycle, does self retain the block? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: *"I know I'm going to get a circular reference"* - bad assumption.

Comment: In this case the block is inline, only the scope is holding the block, there is no retain cycle. A simple test is to put an NSLog() in a dealloc method in the class and see that it gets called when the class instance looses it's retain.

Comment: @zaph Thanks, but this is theoretical question and sample code and I'm telling you it DOES create a retain cycle. I'll make the question clearer.

Comment: @zaph Thanks. I know how to resolve circular references. The question is about clang detecting them - not me detecting them. If you look at the name I gave the method 'saveThisBlockInMyObject' I was hoping to imply the block was retained by the receiver.

Comment: @rmaddy It's not an assumption. It's a fact. My sample code wasn't clear enough, but I did state - 'this causes a circular reference'. I'm not assuming putting self inside causes a circular reference, I know that's not the case.

Comment: @zaph It seems the code example has provided more confusion than help. The question is theoretical regarding clang flagging up circular references. If I have some code I KNOW is a circular ref, and IS a circular ref, why doesn't clang know it is one. Anyway, Vladimir seemed to understand. So I'm happy with that.

Comment: @zaph I've added an example project which shows you the point I'm making: https://github.com/devedup/CircularReferenceExample

Comment: Thanks for the code, it provided the necessary information.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `self` inside of block it does not automatically mean that you get retain cycle. You get retain cycle only if life-time of block depends on life-time of `self` object. That may be the case if `self` has strong reference to `myObject` or some more complex dependencies are also possible (I assume that it indeed 'saves' block passed to a method, so you already have strong reference there).

So to have retain cycle in your example you need to have two following conditions met (neither of them follows from the code you posted), and compiler needs to be aware of them:
1. Life-time of myObject is tied to self - lets assume that self has strong reference to it
2. `saveThisBlockInMyObject:` retains block passed to it

I made a small sample that gives compiler warning about capturing self - to address 1st point I declared myObject as a strong property of some class:

```
@property (strong) MyTestClass* myObj;
...
self.myObj = [MyTestClass new];
```

For 2nd point I could not find a way to specify that method retains its argument (there're [source annotations](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#macosx) for returned values, but there's no relevant annotations for method parameters). But you declare block as a strong property of your test class, then compiler is happy to warn you about possible retain cycle:

```
typedef void (^MyVoidBlock)();
// MyTestClass
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyVoidBlock voidBlock;

self.voidBlock = ^{
    [self doSomething]; // Warning!
};
```

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: But in the OP's case the block is not a property, it is inline, only the scope is holding the block. A simple test is to put an `NSLog()` in a dealloc method in the class and see that it gets called when the class instance looses it's retain.

Comment: that's what I was talking about - we need to tell compiler that block is being retained in the method, but the only way I could find to specify that is for properties (see source annotations link)

Comment: Yes, and are explaining to much, adding a case with a block retained by a property, that is not the case in the question. My explanation would be that there can't be a pointer to the block if it is in-line and thus using self in an in-line block will not cause a retain cycle.

Comment: @zaph, good point, it seems I was answering wrong question :) will delete

Comment: Don't delete the answer, just clean it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I know the rules regarding what causes the retain cycles. So it appears that it just can't determine it based on your second point in that there is nothing in the receivers method declaration that indicates what it does with the block.

Comment: @bandejapaisa, if all other conditions are met, then most likely yes, that's the case

Answer (score 1):

The code posted to github does cause a retain cycle.

Current github code:

```
@interface MyObject ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) dispatch_block_t codeToRunInFuture;
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (void) registerBlockForFuture:(dispatch_block_t)block {
    self.codeToRunInFuture = block;
}

// Call in ViewController
self.myObject = [MyObject.alloc init];
[self.myObject registerBlockForFuture:^{
    [self runThisInFuture];
}];
```

I can see where this would be difficult to catch since the Analyzer can not know what `block` might be and therefore can not tell if there is a self reference either strong or weak. It would have to examine all instances where `registerBlockForFuture:` is called and the `block` in each case.

The answer might be to submit a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) to Apple.